# How to write a Lighttpd plugin to do live streaming

Tags: streaming, lighttpd, live-streaming

I'd like to write a Lighttpd plugin to do streaming..

so far i duplicate the client_socket (con->fd) in the function 'mod_strm_handle_physical'.  So that I can send streaming data thru it in a child process. As for the main process, I set some status to the connection struct to tell the server not to close this conneciton.

Here are how i did in the 'mod_strm_handle_physical' function:

```
URIHANDLER_FUNC(mod_strm_handle_physical)
{
    if(con->uri.path->ptr)
    {
        if(!strcmp("/abcd", con->uri.path->ptr))
        {
            // change Content-Type
            response_header_overwrite(srv, con
                                     , CONST_STR_LEN("Content-Type")
                                     , CONST_STR_LEN("application/octet-stream"));

            con->http_status = 200;
            con->file_finished = 0; // not to close the connection
            con->response.keep_alive = 1;

            int dup_fd = dup(con->fd); // duplicate the client-socket

            int child = fork();
            if(child>0)
                return HANDLER_FINISHED;
            else if(child==0)
            {
                send(dup_fd, STREAMING_DATA, LENGTH, 0);
                close(dup_fd);

                exit(0);
            }
            else
                perror("fork()");
        }
    }

    return HANDLER_GO_ON;
}
```

The problem is..
in this way, the server can do streaming and seems okay. However, the server cannot do more than one streaming at the same time. Is something I am doing wrong?  I though the streaming job is out-process

Comment: Why don't you use existing module ? http://code.google.com/p/lighttpd/ or http://blog.lighttpd.net/articles/2006/03/09/flv-streaming-with-lighttpd ? Or at least, use existing one for example?

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i did read mod_flv_streaming and know how it works. actually I am doing a live-streaming, mod_flv_stream is streaming a file.